# web-routes different return type

Tags: haskell, happstack

Going through [happstack-lite tutorial](http://www.happstack.com/C/ViewPage/9):

we build functions that have return type of `ServerPart Reponse`:

```
homePage :: ServerPart Response
```

however, in [web-routes crash course](http://www.happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/WebRoutes.html#web-routes), our functions change signature to the following:

```
homePage :: RouteT Sitemap (ServerPartT IO) Response
```

Didn't we have ServerPart before, and not ServerPartT?
Also, is there an easier way to switch to web-routes, without changing every method's type signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServerPart` is simply defined as `type ServerPart a = ServerPartT IO a`.  In Happstack 8 we might change this to `type ServerPart = ServerPartT IO` which would mean we could write types like `RouteT Sitemap ServerPart Response`, but until then, we have to use `ServerPartT` directly because type synonyms can't be "partially applied". However, they *are* the same types. That is, `ServerPart Response` is just an alias for `ServerPartT IO Response`.

> Also, is there an easier way to switch to web-routes, without changing every method's type signature?

Not really. I like to define my own type for "handlers" early on, then I can just change its definition. For example, `type Handler = ServerPart Response` and `homePage :: Handler`, and then when I add in web-routes I just redefine Handler `type Handler = RouteT Sitemap (ServerPartT IO) Response`.

Your editor probably has a search-and-replace feature though, for example in Vim:

```
:%s/:: ServerPart Response/:: RouteT Sitemap (ServerPartT IO) Response/g
```